# Running JUnit Test in Eclipse opens console panel

Tags: eclipse, junit

I want to ask you a simple question regarding my development environment configuration for running tests.
I'm using Eclipse Helios and Junit4 and I put all my tests in a separate source folder.
When I run my tests (all, some or just one, it's the same) Eclipse automatically opens the console panel to show the logged information of the class that is being tested.

Is there a way to avoid this and to keep Eclipse on the JUnit view (or panel), thus avoiding  the console panel becoming active as soon as I run my tests?
I tried closing the console panel, but it's reopened when I run tests...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On the top-right of the console panel in Eclipse there are several buttons. Two of the buttons control the "pop-up" behavior of the console. Make sure you deselect both the "Show console when standard out changes" and ""Show console when standard error changes" buttons.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try Run -> Run Config -> Common -> cancel Allocate Console. Does it work for you?

Comment: +1 This works al well, but I dave my preferences to the other solution because is more flexible: that way I can keep my eyes on JUnit panel, and switch to console when I want to check for something. In your solution nothing is written on the console. Thanks anyway, it's a useful information I didn't know

Comment: In this way, you can even config to choose to output to the file (Append is also possible.)